# Is there an optimal combination of gems to items in the game?

Tags: resident-evil-4-2023

In the remake, there is this whole little game of inlaying gems in items.

In a playthrough, assuming you get all gems and inlay items (and assuming that they are not random playthrough to playthrough), is there an optimal path to get the most cash with them?